# Calculating forecast error with time series cross-validation

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have a forecasting model for a time series and I want to calculate its out-of-sample prediction error. At the moment the strategy I'm following is the one suggested on [Rob Hyndman's blog](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/crossvalidation/) (near the bottom of the page) which goes like this (assuming a time series $y_1,\dots,y_n$ and a training set of size $k$)

1. Fit the model to the data $y_t,\dots,y_{t+k-1}$ and let $\hat{y}_{t+k}$ be the forecast for the next observation.
2. Compute the forecast error as $e_{t} = \hat{y}_{t+k} - y_{t+k}$.
3. Repeat for $t=1,\dots,n-k$
4. Compute the mean square error as $\textrm{MSE}=\frac{1}{n-k}\sum_{t=1}^{n-k} e_t^2$

My question is how much I have to worry about correlations because of my overlapping training sets. In particular, say I want to forecast not only the next value, but the next $m$ values, so that I have predictions $\hat{y}_{t+k},\dots,\hat{y}_{t+k+m-1}$ and errors $e_{t,1},\dots,e_{t,m}$, and I want to construct a term-structure of prediction errors.

Can I still roll the window of the training set forward by 1 each time, or should I roll it forward by $m$? How do the answers to these questions change if there is significant autocorrelation in the series that I'm predicting (conceivably it is a long-memory process, i.e. the autocorrelation function decays as a power law rather than exponentially.)

I'd appreciate either an explanation here, or links to somewhere where I can find theoretical results about the confidence intervals around the MSE (or other error measures).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you might be more interested in estimating errors using the [maximum-entropy bootstrap](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v29/i05/paper), rather than cross-validation.  This will allow you to generate multiple bootstraps of you data,  which you can then split into as many train/test sets as you like to calculate confidence intervals for your forecasts.

Rob Hyndman has some further discussion of [time series cross-validation on his blog](http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/tscvexample/), where he implements several different methods of "rolling" and forecasting, but it's mostly focused on implementation.  I have some [further implementations on my blog](http://moderntoolmaking.blogspot.com/2011/11/time-series-cross-validation-2.html) as well. Maybe the simplest approach would be to average your error across all of the time windows, and therefore ignore and potential correlations in errors.

As far as I can tell, the theoretical state of cross-validation for time-series data is somewhat behind the theoretical state of general cross-validation.  Intuitively, I expect error to increase as the horizon increases, which suggests that you should expect correlated errors across various forecast horizons.  Why does this worry you?